# How to read first line in Hadoop (HDFS) file efficiently using Java?

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a large CSV file on my Hadoop cluster. The first line of the file is a 'header' line, which consists of field names. I want to do an operation on this header line, but I do not want to process the whole file. Also, my program is written in Java and using Spark.

What is an efficient way to read just the first line of a large CSV file on an Hadoop cluster?

Comment: Sarcasm? Not sure. If you feel I could have done more, please let me know. Trying to learn how to StackOverflow properly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes Sarcasm.  It would be far better if you said something like, I tried the below, but it has such and such error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access `hdfs` files with [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) class and friends:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem;

DistributedFileSystem fileSystem = new DistributedFileSystem();
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
fileSystem.initialize(new URI("hdfs://namenode-host:54310"), conf);
FSDataInputStream input = fileSystem.open(new Path("/path/to/file.csv"));
System.out.println((new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))).readLine());
```

This code won't use MapReduce and will run with a reasonable speed.

Comment: After reading about how these classes actually work, it seems you are correct! Thank you!