# Bag of Words for each line

Tags: java, csv, hadoop

I currently have a huge csv file. which contains reddit post titles. I would like to create a feature vector for each post.

suppose the post tile is `"to be or not to be"` and it belongs to `"some_category"`. 
the csv file is in the below format.

```
"some_category1", "some title1"

"some_category2", "some title2"

"some_category1", "some title3"
```

I would like to create a feature vector as below.

```
"some_category" : to(2) be(2) or(1) not(1).
```

I need to do this whole thing on hadoop. I am stuck at the very first step, How do i convert each line into a feature vector(I feel its similar to word count but how do i apply it for each line).

My initial thoughts towards this problem was key to each line(i.e. each post's title and category) is the category of the post and the value is the feature vector of the title (i.e. word count of the title.).

Any help is appreciated regarding how to approach this problem.

Comment: Does it have to be a Hadoop Java program, or can you use other Hadoop tools like [Apache Pig](https://pig.apache.org)?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first part:
Reading a csv linewise in Hadoop has been answered in this post:[StackOverflow:how-to-read-first-line-in-hadoop-hdfs-file-efficiently-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188788/how-to-read-first-line-in-hadoop-hdfs-file-efficiently-using-java?rq=1).
Just change the last line to:

```
final Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
while (sc.hastNextLine()) {
    //doStuff with sc.nextLine()!
}
```

To create a feature vector, I would use your mentioned counting strategy:

```
/**
* We will use Java8-Style to do that easily
* 0) Split each line by space separated (split("\\s")
* 1) Create a stream: Arrays.stream(Array)
* 2) Collect the input (.collect) and group it by every identical word (Function.identity) to the corresponding amount (Collectors.counting)
*
* @param title the right hand side after the comma
* @return a map mapping each word to its count
**/
private Map<String, Long> createFeatureVectorForTitle(String title) {
    return Arrays.stream(title.split("\\s").collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Your idea for keying each category to the created feature vector sounds legit. Although I'm not too familiar with Hadoop, perhaps somebody can point out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using two map reduce functions and adding index to make each row unique to process.

```
1, "some_category1", "some title1"

2, "some_category2", "some title2"

3, "some_category1", "some title3"
```

The output of first map reduce

```
"1, some_category" to 2
"1, some_category" be 2
"1, some_category" or 3
"1, some_category" not 1
```

where index and category are the keys to the values i.e. words in the title.

In the second map reduce it final output is of this format.

```
"some_category" : to(2) be(2) or(1) not(1).
```